# PATH_INFO in PHP without having file apparent

Tags: php, pathinfo

I have a simple script:

index.php:

```
<?php

$path= $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

if($path)
  echo $path;
else
  echo "No Path Info";

?>
```

When I run it like so `www.website.com/index.php` it works. ie) `www.website.com/index.php/hello` will echo `/hello`

However, if I go to `www.website.com/hello`, I get a URL not found error when what I want is that `/hello` is echoed.

How do I make it so that `index.php` doesn't have to be present for PATH_INFO to work?!

Comment: What web server are you using? This is really a webserver config question not a php question. You can map all urls to run index.php if you want.

Comment: You need to use rewrites.

Comment: an htaccess rewrite condition is what you need to have here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a webpage is requested from a server. The server looks at the path (i.e. example.com/this/is/a/path) to figure out which file to serve and from where.

As I understand it, what you want to do is have your index.php handle all the requests. The way you would do this to use *URL Rewriting*.

Assuming you are using an apache web server, you can use something called *mod_rewrite* to do this. [See more on mod_rewrite here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

For the specific rules to use, you probably want to use something like the code in V_K's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache web server - write this rule in your .htaccess..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: these rules don't seem to work for subdomains. Forexample, sudomain `mo.website.com` gives me a bad request.

Comment: now its working. very weird. I wrote exactly what you have there and it didnt work. I changed the rule and then changed it back and i did work.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to rewrite in the url settings depending on what server you are using to use clean url's

check this http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

something on these lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: these rules don't seem to work for subdomains. For example, sudomain `mo.website.com` gives me a bad request.

Comment: now its working. very weird. I wrote exactly what you have there and it didnt work. I changed the rule and then changed it back and it did work.