# PHP $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] not returning info without index.php in url (htaccess url rewriting)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a php function which detects `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` and then explodes all the params after `index.php`. And all urls are rewritten using `.htaccess`.

Here's the code for reference:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is my rewriting and my php function work fine locally, but on my test environment server, the function doesn't return `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`without having `index.php` in my url.

For example:

if I go to `example.com/index.php/this/is/a/test`, the function will give me an array like this: `{this, is, a, test}`

but if I go to `example.com/this/is/a/test` rewrites to `index.php` but my function gives me nothing.

I've already seen the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168466/path-info-in-php-without-having-file-apparent), but I think this is more of a server config issue. The server is current running on CentOS, with a OVH RELEASE 3 config (similar to cPanel, ISP Config). web packages are Apache2 and php5.

Appreciate any help coming this way. ✌️

Answer (score 3):

`PATH_INFO` shows the part after a script name.

When the request is `/this/is/a/test`, there is no script and therefore no `PATH_INFO`.

You can work around this by using `REQUEST_URI`, which would include `index.php` in the first case, or add an explicit query string, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

**Update**

It turns out, that I was wrong.
I finally came around testing this with a minimal script

```
<?php
echo "PATH_INFO=", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

and it shows the PATH_INFO with either `index.php/test` or with just `/test`. This is on a Ubuntu 16.04 system with a standard installation.

So to find out what's really going on, one must look into Apache's error log for more details.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Wer'e reconfiguring the apache server to try and get this working. Will update

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know why this is happening specifically with apache2 server in a Linux environment(Me too faced the same issue). As I understand, your code is working perfectly well on a cloud web server without using of "index.php" written on your URL like `http://www.yourdomain.com/login/` but not working like `http://127.0.0.1/login/` and should work like `http://127.0.0.1/index.php/login` for the MVC architecture with .htaccess.

You can overcome this situation in your test environment by using the inbuilt PHP server in the test environment location.
For noobs, If you open your terminal on the location "/var/www/html/" and type `sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:5000` the server will start on the address `http://127.0.0.1:5000`. Now the rewriting of URLs using the same .htaccess will work without using the "index.php" in URL like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/`.